# SQL Lite Case Statement for current_date

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to use the below to determine a warranty status
Always comes up inactive...

```
case 'Status'
   when current_date between  w.start_date and  w.end_date then 'Active'       
   else 'Inactive'
end
```

**Tried this per recommendation:**

```
  case 'Status'
   when date('now') between  w.start_date and w.end_date then 'Active' 
   else 'Inactive'
```

end as status

still nothing.. looking at the data in the db and format is YYYY-MM-DD

Even tried wrapping the columns in date() format..

This shouldn't be brain surgery...

[image]

I do notice that when I export the results to excel the warranty dates are formatted with / and the current date is not...

anyone have any clues?

Comment: You could use `date('now')`;

Comment: Still inactive even tried adding date to the field names...             case 'Status'
       when date('now') between  date(w.start_date) and date(w.end_date) then 'Active'    
       else 'Inactive'
  end as status

Comment: @user2135974, remove  'Status' from case statement and try, also please post data/values for start and end date without looking at them we cannot say if query is returning correct status or not.

Comment: Removed the status.. Worked!!  Thankl YOU!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use [date](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) function, Try this (I'm not sure why you are using `'Status'` in your case statement)

```
case 
    when date('now') between  w.start_date and w.end_date then 'Active'       
    else 'Inactive'
end
```